# StoreKit2 to validate purchase of paid-app

Tags: app-store, storekit

I have a paid-up-front app in the Mac App Store, and I want to verify that the user purchased the app legitimately by verifying the receipt. The StoreKit2 framework (introduced with iOS15/macOS12) claims to have an easy way to do this, but I can't get it to work. From the documentation I've seen, I believe the `Transaction.currentEntitlements` call will only return transactions for IAP and subscriptions. There is another method `Transaction.all` which says it "returns all transaction history", but it's not clear if it should include transactions for paid apps. I've tried running the app (with Xcode debugger attached) I get no results.

Here's how I'm calling it:

```
for await result in Transaction.all {
        
    guard case .verified(let transaction) = result else { continue }
    print("verified product = \(transaction.productID)")
}
```

But I get nothing printed in the console when I run this.
This is what the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/transaction/3851203-all) says about Transaction.all:

> This sequence returns the user’s transaction history current to the
> moment you access the sequence. The sequence emits a finite number of
> transactions. If the App Store processes new transactions for the user
> while you’re accessing this sequence, the new transactions appear in
> the transaction listener, updates. The transaction history doesn’t
> include finished consumable products or finished non-renewing
> subscriptions, repurchased non-consumable products or subscriptions,
> or restored purchases.

Even after reading this, I'm not 100% sure if paid apps transactions *should* show up in the transaction history or not.

Can anyone clarify this? If it should show paid apps in the history, what's the best way to test this out during development (before it's actually in the App Store)?